# Querying Many To Many relationship by number of joins using Django

Tags: python, django, database, many-to-many, django-queryset

I have two models: ActorModel and FilmModel joined as follows:

```
FilmModel(models.Model):
   actors = models.ManyToManyField(Actor, blank=True, related_name='film_actors')

ActorModel(models.Model):
   name = models.CharField(max_length=40)

    def __str__(self):
    return self.imdb_id
```

I want to filter my ActorModel for any instance which has more than 5 joins with the FilmModel. I can do this as follows:

```
actors = ActorModel.objects.all()
more_than_five_films = []

    for actor in actors:
        actor_film_list = FilmModel.objects.filter(actors__imdb_id=str(name))
        if len(actor_film_list)>5:
            more_than_five_films.append(actor)
```

However, using the above code uses lots of processing power. Is there a more efficient way of finding the actors with more than 5 joins? Could I do this at the filtering stage for example?

Comment: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/db/aggregation/

Comment: Thanks still struggling to implement- can you advise?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use query like this:

```
more_than_five_films = ActorModel.objects.annotate(count=Count('film_actors')).filter(count__gt=5)
```

You access `FilmModel` objects of `ActorModel` through `related_name` field, annotate new field named `count` by counting number of `FilmModel` objects related to each `ActorModel` object and then filter out only objects that have count value greater than 5.

**Advice** for code you provided is to never use `len()` on a queryset because it evaluates the whole query which is expensive and not needed since you need only a count value. You should use `count()` function which returns the number as same as `len()` does. It looks like this:

```
FilmModel.objects.filter(actors__imdb_id=str(name)).count()
```

Comment: Thank you! Massively helpful!

Comment: Happy to help! If you found the answer helpful please mark it as Accepted answer (Green tick) and/or give it an upvote.